# Question about example i saw for uniform convergence

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

This is the sequence $f_n(x) = nxe^{−nx}$ on $(0,\infty)$.
Well, i can see that $f_n$ tend to $0$ pointwise for every $x \in (0,\infty)$.
But if i want to check if $f_n$ tend to $0$ ***uniformly*** in $(0,\infty)$, i used the technique and found that for every $n$ the sup of $f_n$ is in $x = \dfrac{1}{n}$.
For every n, $f_n(1/n)$ = $1/e$, So:

$ \sup| f_n(x)-f(x) | =  \dfrac{1}{e} \ne 0$

And therefore, $f_n$ **does not** converge uniformly to $0$ in  $(0,\infty)$.

This is fine proof or am i entirely wrong?

---

**Second question:**

Thanks guys. Here is another question:
$f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1 + nx}$ on $(0,1)$

If i want to use the same technique i used above, i get $f'_n(x)$ = n for every $n$ and for every x.
What can i do to show that is NOT uniformly converges?

Comment: For me it is fine....

Comment: It's fine.${}{}$

Comment: @DavidMitra tnx, i have another question down here! take a look!

Answer (score 0):

For your second question:

**Hint:** if a sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly to some $f$, then $f$ is continuous.

Comment: but f is continuous ..or not?

Comment: Consider $[0,1]$ instead of $(0,1)$. $f(0) = 0$ and $x>0\implies f(x) = 1$.